# using three.js, need to replace the image dynamically

Tags: javascript, image, three.js

I am new to three.js, pls guide me how to change the image dynamically

Tried with the below option of replacing the image from the original image

```
I tried with the below code

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

mtlLoader.load( 't2.mtl', function( materials ) {

materials.preload();            
var texture = THREE.TextureLoader('bbc.png');
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture } );

materials.setMaterials( material );

objLoader.load( 't2.obj', function ( object ) {

scene.add( object );

}, onProgress, onError );
```

});

I am not getting any error but updated image is not displayed ? but the actual object is displayed in blank color. Pls suggest

Thanks
Shaik

Comment: Not sure what if I understood you correctly. three.js is a lot of things, but definitely not something to edit images with.

Comment: There's a very good example of how to use [OBJLoader + MTLLoader](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html)

Comment: If to be honest, I didn't get what you mean "dynamically". Do you mean that you don't want materials from `t2.mtl` at all and just want to apply a material with texture from `bbc.png`?

Comment: if the user clicks on specific part of human body the relavant image material(from t2.mtl) should be highlighted and should able to update the material from browser using three.js

Comment: Pls let me know if any other approach is possible

Comment: I tried with the below code based on the mouse click to show the object being clicked: the stmt console.log returns [ ] blank                                                                  The following is the code snapshot: https://jsfiddle.net/e6r5hc6o/1/